# SQL Query INNER JOIN - unexpected results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have tables:

1. trips: Trip_Num, Trip_Type,Trip_Geographic, etc.
2. travelers_trips_history: Username, Trip_Num, Trip_Type, Trip_Season, etc.

In table 2 there are trips the user did and I need to know what is the most common Trip_Geographic that in his trip's history (The Trip_Geographic need to be known by table 1 - trips by his Trip_Num).

I am doing a project in PHP and need to do a SQL query for a specific user (by his username) - need to receive a table that the columns are: 1. Trip_Geographic, count of the occurrence the Trip_Geographic is in the travelers_trips_history.

Attached the tables I have:
**trips**
[image: trips]

**travelers_trips_history**
[image: travelers_trips_history]

The query I did:

```
$query = "select traveler_trips_history.*, COUNT(trips.Trip_Geographic) AS Trip_Geographic_occurrence 
FROM traveler_trips_history INNER JOIN trips ON 
travelers_trips_history.Trip_Num = trips.Trip_Num 
GROUP BY Trip_Geographic 
ORDER BY Trip_Geographic_occurrence DESC
WHERE traveler_trips_history.Traveler_Username = $username";
```

I receive a error about the Group BY (check syntax), however, I am not sure the query is going to do what it should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues in your query:

**1- You should have the where clause before the GroupBy Clause**

**2- If you GroupBy Col1, you can only select Col1 or use Aggregate Functions on another Columns (SUM, AVG, etc...)**

You need to check the [Rules for GroupBy](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=664143&seqNum=6) and understand it better.

**Edit after your comment:**

```
$query = "select Trip_Geographic, COUNT(*) AS Trip_Geographic_occurrence 
FROM traveler_trips_history INNER JOIN trips ON 
travelers_trips_history.Trip_Num = trips.Trip_Num 
WHERE traveler_trips_history.Traveler_Username = $username
GROUP BY Trip_Geographic 
ORDER BY Trip_Geographic_occurrence DESC";
```

Comment: I can't select the Trip_Geographic and the number of the times it is in the table?

Comment: You are great, Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    SELECT traveler_trips_history.*
    ,COUNT(trips.Trip_Geographic) AS Trip_Geographic_occurrence
FROM traveler_trips_history
INNER JOIN trips ON travelers_trips_history.Trip_Num = trips.Trip_Num
WHERE traveler_trips_history.Traveler_Username = $USERNAME
GROUP BY traveler_trips_history.travelers_trips_history
    ,traveler_trips_history.Username
    ,traveler_trips_history.Trip_Num
    ,traveler_trips_history.Trip_Type
    ,traveler_trips_history.Trip_Season
ORDER BY Trip_Geographic_occurrence DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

The problem is your where clause and group by columns.

```
     SELECT tr.Trip_Geographic
    ,COUNT(hs.*) AS Trip_Geographic_occurrence
FROM traveler_trips_history hs
INNER JOIN trips tr ON hs.Trip_Num = tr.Trip_Num
WHERE hs.Username = $USERNAME
GROUP BY tr.Trip_Geographic
ORDER BY Trip_Geographic_occurrence DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is Haing WHERE clause after GROUP By and using columns that are not in GROUPED BY or AGGREGATE functions.
Try the following which has the username, trip_geographic and the no of trips.

```
select traveler_trips_history.Traveler_Username, traveler_trips_history.Trip_Geographic, COUNT(trips.Trip_Geographic) AS Trip_Geographic_occurrence 
FROM traveler_trips_history INNER JOIN trips ON 
travelers_trips_history.Trip_Num = trips.Trip_Num 
GROUP BY Trip_Geographic, traveler_trips_history.Traveler_Username
having traveler_trips_history.Traveler_Username = $username
ORDER BY Trip_Geographic_occurrence DESC
```

Comment: Why using `having` instead of `where`?

Comment: I added it because I have Traveler_Username in the GROUP BY which allowed it to fetch as a column in the SELECT. You should be able to do it using a WHERE, but still you need to add name column to  GROUP BY clause. You should use one that is more performance friendly according to your schema.